# Rotating wheel acceleration

Tags: linear-algebra

A wheel is rotating and slowing down. At some point it makes one rotation in 1s and next rotation in 1.2s.
After it made 1s rotation would it be possible to calculate how long will take ¼ rotation later to make a rotation.  It will be close to 1.050s but it needs to be a bit less.

Comment: Is there are any way as to look acceleration as the wheel slows down 200ms / 1.2s

Comment: To answer this, you need some assumption about the _way_ the wheel decelerates, e.g., the angular deceleration (rate of change of angular velocity with respect to time) is constant. Separately (once the first question is answered), do you want an exact ("analytic") answer, or is a numerical approximation enough?

Comment: Numerical approximation could be enough.

Comment: This is how I think.
1s rotation have had wheel speed of 360deg/s in the moment which is half time earlier 0.5s. Same with 1.2s (0.6s).
So the acceleration would be (360/1.2 – 360/1 )/(0.5 + 0.6)
Than I would need to calculate speed after 90deg. Then time1 = time2 where time 1 is wheel traveling forward and  time 2 wheel is traveling backwards until it makes one rotation distance. 
But this looks as very complicated calculation, wondering if there is something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\omega(t)$ denote the total angular turning of the wheel (in degrees) after $t$ seconds, so that $\omega'(t)$ is the rotation rate at time $t$ in degrees per second.

> At some point it makes one rotation in $1$s and next rotation in $1.2$s.

There are two natural (but logically distinct) ways to interpret this sentence:

1. In terms of rates: $\omega'(0) = 360$ (one rotation per second initially) and $\omega'(1) = 300$ (one rotation in $1.2$ seconds after one second).
2. In terms of increments: $\omega(1) - \omega(0) = 360$ (one rotation in the first second) and $\omega(2.2) - \omega(1) = 360$ (one rotation in the next $1.2$ seconds).

> After it made $1$s rotation would it be possible to calculate how long will take $1/4$ rotation later to make a rotation.

Mathematically, you're looking for the smallest time $t_{0}$ such that $\omega(t_{0}) = 450$, and then you want either $\omega'(t_{0})$ (with the first interpretation) or you want $t_{1} - t_{0}$, where $\omega(t_{1}) = 450 + 360 = 810$ (with the second interpretation).

To proceed, let's assume the angular acceleration is constant and see how each of the preceding interpretations works out:

1. Since $\omega''$ is constant, we have $\omega'(t) = 360 - 60t$. Calculus gives
   $$
   \omega(t) = 360t - 30t^{2}.
   \tag{1}
   $$
   In this model, $\omega(t_{0}) = 450$ when $t_{0}^{2} - 12t_{0} + 15 = 0$. By the quadratic formula, $t_{0} = 6 \pm \sqrt{36 - 15} = 6 \pm \sqrt{21}$. The smallest solution greater than $1$ is $t_{0} \approx 1.417$s.

   At this time, the angular speed is $60\sqrt{21} \approx 275$ degrees per second, so the next rotation takes about $1.3$ seconds.
2. Here, we assume the quadratic function $\omega(t) = at^{2} + bt + c$ passes through the three points $(0, 0)$, $(1, 360)$, and $(2.2, 720)$. Plugging these values into the quadratic and solving for the coefficients gives
   $$
   a = -\frac{3600}{132} = -\frac{300}{11},\quad
   b = \frac{4260}{11},\quad
   c = 0,
   $$
   or
   $$
   \omega(t) = \tfrac{60}{11}(-5t^{2} + 71t).
   \tag{2}
   $$
   In this model, $\omega(t_{0}) = 450$ when $10t_{0}^{2} - 142t_{0} + 165 = 0$. By the quadratic formula,
   $$
   t_{0} = \frac{142 \pm \sqrt{142^{2} - 40 \cdot 165}}{20}.
   $$
   The smallest solution greater than $1$ is $t_{0} \approx 1.277$s.

   The amount of time it takes to make the next full rotation in this model is found by solving $\omega(t_{1}) = 810$, and taking $t_{1} - t_{0}$. I leave this to you if this is the interpretation you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but it looks it is 1+1/4 later from 1s rotation, it should be only ¼ after 1s rotation so the result should be close to 1.050s. In the first example I can see you sued 450, but it should be 90. The second one a bit hard to follow.

The problem I have is that I am using a small processor to calculate it and never used sqr. Some other problem where I had to use it I actually calculated distance and changed time, then repeat it until the time created distance I need. I know it the acceleration is not constant it would be impossible to calculate it. Reality it that it is not but I have to ignore it.

For explained situation I would just use ¼ of differences in between rotations as 1.050s but I know it is a bit less than 1050, so Looking for simple solution to get closer to the correct value. For example it may be 1.040 If I can come with estimation to 1.042 it is still better than 1.050.

For example the wheel may spin 880ms, 1000ms , 1200ms 1400ms per rotation.  So the acceleration is not same. ¼ of rotation later it would be about  910, 1050, 1250. The best would be is somehow difference in between rotations as 1200-1000=200ms I can use to readjust value 1050.